# How to measure speech file similarity

Tags: speech-recognition, speech, audio-fingerprinting

I have two speech audio files. Each one is recorded from a phone call conversation and they differ in the length (first file is 3 seconds long but second file is 5 seconds long). I want to measure the similarity of the two files. Note that I am not interested in the text content in the speech signal (i.e. NO Speech to Text). I need to just measure the similarity and get a score or percentage.

I found few tools that do audio fingerprint analysis but I found almost all of them are targeted towards music audio files and not perform well when its speech.

Comment: Already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841333/need-help-in-developing-speech-similarity-tool

Comment: Dear Nikolay, could you answer it. Thanks for adding this comment. Hope to get your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Audio Fingerprint should not works to find similarity, Audio Fingerprint should be used when do you have a audio or piece of audio exactly identical.

You maybe need collect a set of features like Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficients (MFFCs) and use one classification method like HNN to tell you the similarity ( hard work ) lol